# StackExchange.Redis ConnectionMultiplexer life cycle management in web scenario

Tags: asp.net, redis, ninject, inversion-of-control, stackexchange.redis

What is the correct lifecycle management of the ConnectionMultiplexer instance in a web scenario. 
As I understand it manages individual requests by pipelining them and thus reduces the negative effect caused by latency. Does that mean that in a web application the ConnectionMultiplexer should be used as a singleton as opposed to the more frequently used request scope?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essentially, yes - you should rarely need more than one multiplexer to the same Redis nodes. This is also described [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/docs/Basics.md). Note that the *database* object from GetDatabase is very cheap, and can be per request or per method-scope if needed (per-rewuest plays very nicely for multi-tenancy scenarios where different tenants are on different database numbers)